# Disable collapse on clicking links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 issues. The first is that when a user clicks a link (Say About Us), the entire menu closes. This is a bad UX. I would like it to remain open since it's already open.

The second issue is that users can't close the active main menu once opened (say Terms, Private or Sub Main). How can we resolve both this issues?

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/edvh0nsk/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ul class="nav police mod-list">
              <li class="item-103 deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img class="float-right" src="/images/arrow-down.png"  /><span class="image-title">Terms</span></span>
                <ul class="nav-child unstyled small" style="display: none;">
                    <li class="item-106"><a href="/">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="item-107 active deeper parent"><span class="nav-header "><img class="float-right" src="/images/arrow-down.png" /><span class="image-title">Private</span></span>
                  <ul class="nav-child unstyled small" style="display: none;">
                    <li class="item-104"><a href="/">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li class="item-105 current active"><a href="/">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="item-108 deeper parent"><span class="nav-header ">Sub Main</span>
                      <ul class="nav-child unstyled small" style="display: none;">
                          <li class="item-109"><a href="/">Child</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.police .active .nav-child {
    display: block !important;
}
.police .active.parent .nav-header{
    font-weight: 600;
}
.police .parent {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px 0;
}
.police .nav-child {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.police .nav-child li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 7px 0;
}
.police .parent span img {
    width: 24px;
}
.police .parent.arrow span img {
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery('.police .nav-child').hide();
jQuery('.police .parent').click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("arrow");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/70Lkw3an/

You need to get rid of `!important` here:

```
.police .active .nav-child {
    display: block !important;
}
```

So that `.slideToggle` can actually close it.  Then you need to prevent clicking on links from propagating to the parent so that it doesn't close the menu:

```
jQuery('a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

To prevent hiding the active one initially:

```
jQuery('.police .nav-child:not(.active > .nav-child)').hide();
```

Comment: If I remove the `display: block !important;` then the active menu closes. I would like to have the active menu to remain open. Any idea how can I achieve this? Thank You so much.

Comment: Thank You. However, when I moved the `active' class and `current active` classes to `Terms`, it doesn't work.